# Use of the same symbol - why it's allowed for variable/class but not for others?

Tags: c++, redefinition

Somewhat it's allowed to use the same symbol `T` for variable-id and class-id as below:

```
struct S
{
    int T = 0;
    struct T{};
};
```

in which case, `struct T` is *hidden* by `int T`.

However, for other cases like below, they're considered as redefinition and are not allowed:

```
struct S
{
    int T = 0;

    template<class>
    struct T{}; // error!

    using T = int; // error!
};
```

What's the rationale for the inconsistency and any good reason to allow the case in the 1st example?